# django-react cannot fetch data properly

Tags: reactjs, django

**models.py**

```
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    passcode = models.CharField(max_length=80)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Book
        fields = '__all__'
```

**views.py**

```
class GetBooks(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        books = models.Book.objects.all()
        data = serializers.BookSerializer(books, many=True).data
        return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('get-books', views.GetBooks.as_view(), name='get-books')
]
```

**Main.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class Main extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            books: ''
        }
        
        this.getBooks()
    }

    getBooks() {
        fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/get-books') // go down to see the data
            .then((response) => {
                const books = response.json()
                console.log(books) // go down to see the output <---- !!
                this.setState({
                    books: books
                })
            })
            
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
               // for book in books show book.name, book.author ...
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

**Books data from (http://localhost/api/get-books)**

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "book1",
        "author": "author1",
        "passcode": "123"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "book2",
        "author": "auhthor2",
        "passcode": "123"
    }
]
```

**console.log(data)**

```
Promise { <state>: "pending" }
​
<state>: "fulfilled"
​
<value>: Array [ {…}, {…} ]
​​
0: Object { id: 1, name: "book1", author: "author1", … }
​​
1: Object { id: 2, name: "book2", author: "author2", … }
​​
length: 2
​​
<prototype>: Array []
```

> I want to iterate through all the books and display it to the user, the fetched data return as an array but I cant access it from this.state.books (i just recently started using react and django so please have mercy...)

Answer (score 1):

**I FOUND A SOLUTION**

**Main.js**

```
import axios from 'axios'
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Books from './Books'

export default class Main extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            books: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/get-books')
            .then(res => {
                this.setState({
                    books: res.data
                })
            })
            
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Books books={this.state.books} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

**Books.js**

```
import React from 'react'

const Books = ({books}) => {
    return (
        <div>
            {books.map(book => (
                <div> 
                    <h1>{book.name}</h1>
                    <small>{book.author}</small>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Books
```

> I simply used axios, put the data in an array and sent it to Book.js, then used the .map() to iterate through them!